# JIRA REST API -- How to Query On Issue Status Name

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using the JIRA REST API and I would like to query for all issues in "Resolved" status. The status field looks like this:

```
"status": {
      "self": "https:\/\/jira.atlas.xx.com\/rest\/api\/2\/status\/5",
      "description": "A resolution has been taken, and it is awaiting verification by reporter. From here issues are either reopened, or are closed.",
      "iconUrl": "https:\/\/jira.atlas.xx.com\/images\/icons\/statuses\/resolved.png",
      "name": "Resolved",
      "id": "5",
      "statusCategory": {
        "self": "https:\/\/jira.atlas.xx.com\/rest\/api\/2\/statuscategory\/3",
        "id": 3,
        "key": "done",
        "colorName": "green",
        "name": "Complete"
      }
    }
```

Currently the only way to know to do this is to query for status=5. It would be nice to make the query more intuitive and look for all issues using the string "Resolved" status. Here is the query I'm using:

```
https://jira.atlas.xx.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=MYPROJECT and status=5 and fixVersion=15824&fields=id,key,description,status
```

Is it possible to query on status name?

Comment: **Why is this so difficult?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can query on status name as well.

I think you should use the official Jira documentation, especially [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) when using advanced searching options like JQL queries.

This documentation describes every part of your possible JQL queries. If you look at the [Fields reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-fieldfieldsFieldsReference) section, there you will find the fields as well as the possible attributes on which you can search. For example, in case of [Status](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-Status) field:

```
You can search by Status name or Status ID (i.e. the number that JIRA automatically allocates to a Status).
```

According to this, your query can be modified easily

```
https://jira.atlas.xx.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=MYPROJECT and status=Resolved and fixVersion=15824&fields=id,key,description,status
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can type the JQL in the browser, you can use it as a string for the REST API search resource. So you can indeed search by status name, suitable quoted

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I mean that you can have a JQL query such as

PROJECT=MYPROJECT and status = Done

but if the status has more than one word you have to write

PROJECT=MYPROJECT and status = "In Progress"